# Is it possible to measure a 433MHz RF Transceiver signal using a 100MHz Oscilloscope? At least to see if it is transmitting or not

Tags: rf, oscilloscope, measurement, transceiver

I'm generating a serial signal and feeding it to a 433MHz RF Transceiver and I want to know if the signal is at least being transported before I starting working on the receiving end.

Comment: Do you mean if anything comes out, or if it is the correct data? For the later, you might want to have a look into rtl-sdr

Answer (score 1):

Following on from PlasmaHH's comment - yes, absolutely use RTL-SDR. For that you will need:

- an RTL-SDR compatible tuner (search eBay for RTL2832U - should be around $10)
- an RTL-SDR software package - I use [gqrx](http://gqrx.dk/)

Set up gqrx according to the instructions on its website, and then set the centre frequency of the display to 433 MHz (actually probably more likely 433.92 MHz - take a close look at the label. Be sure to enable automatic gain control and you should see bursts when you transmit using your source.

You may see some aliased signals on a 100 MHz scope, but you can't trust them as they are outside of the scope's spec. Use RTL-SDR - it's what I use for debugging 433 stuff and it has never failed me.

Answer (score 1):

Constructing a simple wavemeter is one technique. It consists of a 433 MHz tuned circuit with a tap on the coil connected to a diode detector and a 50 uA meter. A few inches of wire should be adequate as a simple antenna. The meter will indicate when the transmitter is operating. Examples will be found in the amateur radio literature.